# UseDapp - How to get return value from a solidity function from react typescript?

Tags: reactjs, solidity, react-tsx

I was building an app with ethereum chain.
I've built a **solidity contract** here's it as follows:

**`Solidity code::`**

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.10;

contract HelloWorld {

 string public message;

 constructor(string memory initMessage) public {
    message = initMessage;
 }

 function update(string memory newMessage) public {
    message = newMessage;
    }
}
```

I have to call the update function. with **react typescript**

This is my old contract in which i was able to call the `setQuote` method which is done by doing transaction.

**`My old contract's code :`**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract QuoteV2{
    string private quote;
    event quoteUploaded(string newQuote);
    
    // mapping(address => string) public users;

    struct userQuoteTime {
        mapping(address => string) u;
        string _quote;
        string _time ;        
        
    
    }
    
    struct newUser {
            string userName;
            address walletAddress;
    }

    mapping (uint256 => newUser) public users;

    event newUserCame(uint256 indexed _userId);
    uint256 public userCount;

    function setQuote(string memory _quote) public {
        quote = _quote;
        emit quoteUploaded(_quote);
    }
    function getQuote() public view returns(string memory){
        return quote;
    }

    function newUserF(address _walletAddress, string memory _userName) public {
        newUser memory User;
        User.userName = _userName;
        User.walletAddress = _walletAddress;

        users[userCount] = newUser(_userName, _walletAddress);
        userCount++;

    }
    // function getUsers() public view returns(newUser memory) {
    //     return users;
    // }
    function getUsers() public view returns (newUser[] memory){
      newUser[] memory id = new newUser[](userCount);
      for (uint i = 0; i < userCount; i++) {
          newUser storage user = users[i];
          id[i] = user;
      }
      return id;
  }

}
```

Can anyone help me??
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Going through [this](https://dapp-world.com/smartbook/interact-solidity-contract-functions-in-javascript-7eI0) might help

Comment: @RahulK This gives me an error `Uncaught TypeError: tokenFarmContract.methods is undefined`

Comment: @RahulK I just want to call a function without doing any transaction

Comment: @RahulK And if I call this `const AF = () => {
  console.log(tokenFarmContract)
  tokenFarmContract.functions.getQuote().then((res:any) => {
    alert(res);
}).catch((err:any) => {
    alert(err);
})
}` I am getting **TypeError: signerOrProvider is null**

Comment: Have you not used web3 and other required packages to connect your solidity with JS. If not try exploring them. I don't know what you mean "just" call and not transact

Comment: @RahulK I have used useDApp. mean that I just have to Call the function like from [this function](https://usedapp-docs.netlify.app/docs/api%20reference/hooks/#usecall) But i cannot find a way to use It. But I have succeed in calling a function that does a transaction. I will update the contract that I've used before